# Searchview like Youtube app

Tags: android, search, android-fragments, youtube

what i am trying to implement is the ability for the user to search through the app. I want to do something like Youtube app as looks in the Screenshot below

[image]

The thing is that i dont know how to implement it into my app.

I have started with the options menu but for some reason the icon does not get displayed in the toolBar

My Code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:activity=".ProductsNewOrder">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:visible="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item android:id="@+id/cart"
        android:title="Cart"
        android:visible="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

The searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search"
    android:hint="@string/search" >
</searchable>
```

Manifest.xml

And where i create the options menu:

```
public class ProductsViewOrder extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ProductsTabPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_order);
        getActionBar().setElevation(0);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("tableID");
        getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.table_id) + title);
        mAdapter = new ProductsTabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), ProductsViewOrder.this, ProductsViewOrder.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
        tabs.setDividerColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        tabs.setIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);
        tabs.setIndicatorHeight(6);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_order, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.search:{
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.cart:{
                return true;
            }
            default:{
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showSearchResults() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left);
    }
}
```

When i tap on search icon nothing happens.

Anyone can help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PersistentSearch library [link](https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch)

Just a simple search with google :)

Comment: i am not able to add it as a dependency though... have you tried?

Comment: yes, did you add maven? maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }

Comment: it gives me this error:

Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch:library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: how to add maven and in which file?

Comment: into your gradle, look in the sample build.gradle here: https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch/blob/master/sample/build.gradle

Comment: when i add it to my layout it gives me this error:

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch.SearchBox

Comment: did you build it with gradle first? check if you can call SearchBox from your activity, just follow the sample in git it should be easy to understand

Comment: PersistentSearch is not what OP is looking for. He is looking for expandable search.